# Как очищать sharedPreferences каждый новый день

Tags: java, android

Нужно очищать `sharedPreferences` каждый день. Пробовал гуглить, но не нашел.

Думаю, что можно как-то сохранять дату (день, год, месяц) в `sharedPreferences` и при запуске приложения каждый раз сравнивать с сохраненной и если они не равны, то удалять все по ключам из `sharedPreferences` и создавать уже новую дату. Но не знаю как получить дату в таком формате, чтобы можно было без проблем сравнить.

Comment: Ну просто через форматную строку Год Месяц День сохраняйте.

Comment: @Style-7 уже пробовал, при сравнении 2х  одинаковых строк с условием a != b выдает true

Comment: так строки в Java не так сравнивают

Comment: @Style-7, а как? через equals?

Comment: ну да или equalsIgnoreCase

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Важно решить, когда по вашему начинается новый день, например будем считать, что новый день начинается в полночь.

```kotlin
fun getLastValidTimestamp(): Long {
        val day = Calendar.getInstance()
        day[Calendar.MILLISECOND] = 0
        day[Calendar.SECOND] = 0
        day[Calendar.MINUTE] = 0
        day[Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY] = 0
        return day.time.time
}
```

Этот метод вернет временную метку полночи, которая уже была.

Что бы решить наступил ли новый день нужно:

1. Сохранить результат метода getLastValidTimestamp(). (Только при первом запуске, когда у вас дефолтное значение)
2. При каждом запуске сравнить сохраненный результат с новым

Пример условия:

```kotlin
fun isNewDay(lastValue: Long): Boolean {
    return getLastValidTimestamp() > lastValue
}
```

Где `lastValue` последний сохраненный результат из пункта 1.

3. В случаи если метод `isNewDay` вернул `true`, необходимо повторить пункт 1.

Пример на java

```java
public long getLastValidTimestamp() {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
        return calendar.getTime().getTime();
}
```

Comment: Пишу на java, поэтому немного не понял эти строки:  
val day = Calendar.getInstance()
return day.time.time
day это long массив?

Comment: Добавил код выше

Comment: @Shadowlight добавил код на java. Не забывайте, что пункт 1 нужно выполнить только первый запуск. И записать новое значение, только если у нас новый день. Иначе вы будете сравнивать одно и тоже.  Как это сделать? Проверяйте пустые ли у вас данные, для long по умолчанию устанавливается 0L. Вот если у вас 0L, тогда запишите первую запись.

Comment: Заработало, большое вам спасибо

Comment: @Shadowlight Обращайтесь!